# preg_split and square brackets

Tags: php, regex

Thanks in advance, I'm terrible at REGEX!

Lets say I have a string eg:

```
[GROUP]Some Stuff[GROUP]Some more stuff[GROUP]Some other stuff
```

I want to split the string at the [GROUP], pop the results into an array eg:

```
Array( [0] => Some Stuff [1] => Some more stuff [2] => Some other stuff )
```

Using the following

```
$groups = preg_split("[GROUP]", $p['features']);
```

But it leaves behind the [ and ] in my array.

```
Array( [0] => [ [1] => ]Some Stuff[ [2] => ]Some more stuff[ [3] => ]Some other stuff )
```

I'm sure there must be some fancy method of escaping or slashes or brackets or something to get this working but I'm not having any luck with my random shots.  Googling generally tells me how to get the text out from between the square brackets, but not quite helping me to do what I want to do.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[]` is used for a character class, so you need to escape them.  You also need delimiters (here I use `#`) because in your regex the `[]` are acting as delimiters:

```
$groups = preg_split("#\[GROUP\]#", $p['features']);
```

To only return non-empty groups use `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY`:

```
$groups = preg_split("#\[GROUP\]#", $p['features'], null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

If you want `GROUP` to be variable then use `[` followed by 1 or more NOT `]` followed by a `]`:

```
"#\[[^\]]+\]#"
```

This will split on `[SOMETHING ELSE]` etc...

Comment: I'm marking this as correct because it technically answers my question, unfortunately the outcome was not quite what I wanted - was hoping to avoid the empty element at [0] in my array.  Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Then use `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` as the fourth parameter.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use regex for this if you don't want to (and if requirements permit):

```
$string = "[GROUP]Some Stuff[GROUP]Some more stuff[GROUP]Some other stuff";
$array = explode('[GROUP]', $string);
```

Produces:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => Some Stuff
    [2] => Some more stuff
    [3] => Some other stuff
)
```

If you want to remove the empty element and reindex:

```
unset($array[0]);
$array = array_values($array);
```

Alternatively, to avoid empty elements at the beginning or end altogether, use `trim()`:

```
$string = "[GROUP]Some Stuff[GROUP]Some more stuff[GROUP]Some other stuff";
$array = explode('[GROUP]', trim($string, '[GROUP]'));
```

Produces:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Some Stuff
    [1] => Some more stuff
    [2] => Some other stuff
)
```

Comment: Yeah, I had been hoping to find something that would avoid the necessity of pulling out the empty element.  It seems that preg_split as below though leaves me in the same position.

Comment: @Sanfly I added another option which avoids having to do it after the split. Using `trim()`.